# Has a recent update broken mathbf when using mathspec?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, mathspec

The following MWE illustrates code that was working until sometime over the last couple weeks.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \nabla \times \mathbf{B} = \mu_0 \mathbf{J}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I now get a warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/bx/n' undefined (Font) using `TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n' instead on input line 13.
```

I update my LaTeX packages weekly, so I'm not sure which package or version caused the change in behavior.

I suspect an issue with `fontspec` since it was updated recently and `mathspec` hasn't been updated in years. However, the warning message does not manifest when using `fontspec` instead:

```latex
...
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
...
```

Has a bug been introduced somewhere that can explain this?

`mathspec` is version 0.2b, but doesn't appear to have been updated since 2016.
`fontspec` was recently updated (Feb. 3) and is now version 2.7h.

Is `mathspec` no longer maintained? Or should `fontspec` be used directly (`mathspec` loads `fontspec`)?

Comment: this may be due to the changes in latex23 2020-02-02 handling of bold, see ltnews31 will investigate....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is clearly due to the new LaTeX kernel using `b` as the default value for `\bfseries`.

Probably `fontspec` should also define `bx` weight for compatibility, but in the meantime you can patch `mathspec` to use `b` instead of `bx`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\setmathrm}{bx}{b}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\setmathrm}{bx}{b}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\setmathrm}{bx}{b}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\setmathsf}{bx}{b}{}{}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\eu@get@familyseriesshape}{bx}{b}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@eu@mkern}{bx}{b}{}{}
\makeatother

\setallmainfonts{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\nabla \times \mathbf{B} = \mu_0 \mathbf{J}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: While Ulrike's answer appears simpler, it must be implemented after the font declaration. This kluge can be implemented before the font declaration, which suits my particular application better.

Comment: Why three identical lines `\xpatchcmd{\setmathrm{bx}{b}{}{}`?

Comment: @mrclary Because there are three occurrences of `bx` to do with and `\xpatchcmd` does only one replacement.

Answer (score 6):

You can add a declaration so that the text font knows bx too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts{Times New Roman}
\DeclareFontShape{TU}{\familydefault}{bx}{n}{<-> ssub*\familydefault/b/n}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \nabla \times \mathbf{B} = \mu_0 \mathbf{J}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

fontspec will probably do this by default in the next version.

Comment: Simpler and without using `\normalfont` is `\DeclareFontShape{TU}{\familydefault}{bx}{n}{<-> ssub*\familydefault/b/n}{}`

Comment: @egreg right, I obviously overcomplicated. I edited the answer.