# Issues regarding fonts in MiKTeX after updates

Tags: fonts, math-fonts, mathdesign

I have been trying to compile a simple TeX file and have been getting the following error.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\RequirePackage{amsbsy,amsmath,amsthm,dsfont,latexsym,alltt,array} 
\RequirePackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\RequirePackage{mathtools}
\RequirePackage{enumitem} 

\pagestyle{empty}
\linespread{1.1}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{(\alph*).}]
\item Answer the following
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 2.9.7300 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.2.29)  29 FEB 2020 15:36
>
> LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 4 L3 programming layer <2020-02-25>
>   ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls" Document
>   Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
>   ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size11.clo" File:
>   size11.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option) )
>
> LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/mdugm/b/n' in size <12> not available
>   (Font)              Font shape`T1/mdugm/bx/n' tried instead on input line 17.
>
> No declaration for shape T1/mdugm/mb/n.
>   sub@sfcnt ...e forspace shapespace mandatory@arg }
>                                                     error@fontshape else #1
>
> ! No declaration for shape T1/mdugm/mb/fsc.
>   sub@sfcnt ...e forspace shapespace mandatory@arg }
>                                                     error@fontshape else #1

After I ignore the errors the file compiles but the fonts are different and there is no **bold** font appearing anywhere.

I tried a few things: `\usepackage{anyfontsize}`, and by downloading garamond fonts etc. but to no avail. Can someone give me some pointers how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you supply an MWE illustrating the issue? Is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528909/has-a-recent-update-broken-mathbf-when-using-mathspec related?

Comment: Say also which latex version you are using

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have added a MWE and also the TeX version. I just updated the MiKTeX on a different machine and the file that was working before the update started showing the same errors. Something to do with bold fonts.

Comment: @Cicada I have added MWE.

Comment: with latex format I meant the line in the log starting with "latex" and then a date.

Comment: it will hopefully work again with the next update of latex which should happen in 1 or 2 days (I have it already in texlive). Until then you can either comment the mathdesign package or try to compile with pdflatex-dev.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for your help. I will comment out the mathdesign for now.